# vlfeat matlab error Attempt to execute SCRIPT vl_imsmooth as a function:

Tags: computer-vision, matlab, pattern-recognition

I am trying to use the VLFEAT function vl_imsmooth but matlab gives me an error:
'Attempt to execute SCRIPT vl_imsmooth as a function:'

Why this happens?

Might it be because of some mex files?
Should I recompile the c++ code for vl_feat?

Comment: What is the output of `which vl_imsmooth`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem shuold be fixed by copying correct mexw32 or mexw64 file folder from ..\vlfeat\toolbox\mex to ..\vlfeat. In my case my operating system is 64 bit My folder looks like ..\vlfeat\mexw64

Answer (score 8):

You are getting this error because your path ".../vlfeat-0.9.16/toolbox/imop/vl_imsmooth.m"
has a higher precedence than " ...../vlfeat-0.9.16/toolbox/mex/mexa64/vl_imsmooth.mexa64"
so you can simply run

> > pathtool

and then navigate the mexa64 path above the imop and you are done !!